# Is it possible to make the Kerberos Server use LDAP for just the crendential validation, and use a local Keberos Principal DB for everything else?

Tags: ldap, openldap, kerberos, mitkerberos

We are working with a **LDAP setup that we can not change or extend**. We need to add a Kerberos Server to the environment.

Is it possible to make the Kerberos Server use LDAP for just the *crendential validation*, and use a local Kerberos Principal DB for everything else?

Comment: I would say no, but I am lacking a lot of details. My pessimistic evaluation arise from the setup required to have Kerberos store data on LDAP. It is quite some job and requires some forethought. You are asking for something even more complex and you don't have control on LDAP. So I would say that is going to be hard.